# Why does Spring consider two classes from different packages equal?

Tags: java, spring

My Spring application contains a package `v2` with the following content:

```java
package some.path.v2;

public interface Builder { ... }
```

```java
package some.path.v2;

@Component
public class DefaultBuilder implements Builder { ... }
```

And it contains a package `v3` with very similar content:

```java
package some.path.v3;

public interface Builder { ... }
```

```java
package some.path.v3;

@Component
public class DefaultBuilder implements Builder { ... }
```

Upon startup, Spring throws the following error:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [some.path.Application]; nested exception is org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'defaultBuilder' for bean class [some.path.v3.DefaultBuilder] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [some.path.v2.DefaultBuilder]

Do I understand correctly that Spring considers the completely different interface implementations **v2**.DefaultBuilder and **v3**.DefaultBuilder the same because the beans are registered under the same name "defaultBuilder"?

Does giving the beans different names solve this conflict? So for example, if I turn the two `@Component`s into `@Component("defaultBuilderV2")` and `@Component("defaultBuilderV3")`, will the rest of the setup work?

Or does that then mean that I also need to adjust all consumers? I mean: I use `@Autowired private some.path.v2.Builder myAttribute` to autowire those beans. Do I need to then qualify all those with `@Autowired @Qualifier("defaultBuilderV2")`?

Comment: Yes, you need to give your beans different names. No, as long as there is only a single implementation, Spring should be able to autowire it, without specifying the name of the bean.

Comment: Similar to id in CSS, you are allowed to have only one. The same goes for any bean name.